# Running potentially unstable code securely

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am developing an app for Windows 8.1 which needs to run code that is potentially unstable in that it might run into a stack overflow exception. I am in control of that code, but I can't possible prohibit all corner cases in which it might crash, so I'd prefer a solution to execute that code in a way that I can gracefully handle potential crashes.

I have read of `AppDomain`s, but everything I found online focused on running code with restricted permissions or the benefits that AppDomains bring regarding unloading assemblies. Also, it seems like a massive overkill to implement a service host so that I can communicate across AppDomains.
And finally, I am not even sure the restricted runtime for Windows 8.1 apps even allows (a) creating AppDomains and (b) hosting a WCF Service or Remoting Host.

So what I am asking for is, is there a simpler alternative?

[Edit:] I may not have been clear about this, but I **can't** change the fact that these exceptions might occur. And that's fine with me! In fact, I have implemented recursion depth counters and similar measures, but it still holds that the user has very direct control and may provoke an exception. 
**I do not want to prohibit that, I want to handle it gracefully.**

Comment: I'm in no way saying this is the right solution, or suggesting that you haven't already tried it, but using a `try{}catch{}` stops the program from crashing, but instead does anything you specify in the `catch{}` block.

Comment: @Ben That's the point, try-catch can **not** guard against a `StackOverflowException`. It's non-recoverable.

Comment: If you create a new thread, you get a new stack. I'm not entirely sure that will help you though, since you can't reliably catch a StackOverflowException. But it might work.

Comment: @Kris Well, I would have to reliably diagnose it. Also, I am not sure a stack overflow in a thread wouldn't affect the process as a whole, but I'm going to look into it.

Comment: @Kris I just threw some threads together and unfortunately, the Exception brought down the whole application.

Comment: An unhandled exception in a normal .NET thread would certainly affect the process as a whole. But in a Windows 8.1 app, you have the option to use native WinRT threads directly. I haven't used those, so I don't know, but they just might have an UnhandledException event or something. Or they might even behave differently with respect to StackOverflowexception being non-recoverable, I don't know. In any case, to isolate your problem, you need a stack. And stacks come with threads, not with AppDomains.

Comment: Then again, good code shouldn't have StackOverflowExceptions. What are you trying to do? Have you tried eliminating tail recursions manually? Use explicit `Stack<T>` collections? Reduce the number of local variables? Convert big structs used for local variables into classes? It might be easier to remove the cause of this exception, than to try to handle it.

Comment: Please believe me when I tell you there's no way to avoid that Exception. Actually, it *kind of* is desired behaviour- the user is free to provoke a recursion that might blow over. I need to handle this since I can't forbid it. There are a few obvious situations where I could diagnose such an outcome beforehand, but I can't cover all corner cases as stated in the orginal question.

Comment: If you think that an AppDomain is already too much work then you are never going to like the real answer.  Running unstable code in a separate process is a hard requirement.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you implying the real answer in fact is 'use an AppDomain'? Because that would be fine with me after all. I was just optimistic that the framework might give me a hand with this.

Comment: No, a separate process is not an appdomain.  You'll get plenty of help from the framework to talk to such a process, it supports inter-process communication well.  Recovering from the process suddenly dying is something you'll have to deal with yourself however, recovering state is invariably difficult.

Comment: @HansPassant I see. But does WinRT actually allow me to spawn a process? I might be wrong here, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: It is possible, nothing simple.  There's a "works like Skype" code sample in the gallery that demonstrates the technique, I forgot its name. Never realized this was about WinRT, AppDomain isn't available.  Maybe you shouldn't worry about it that much, Store apps terminate unexpectedly all the time anyway :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I'll look into it! I expected this to get dirty, but having an actual approach might make it bearable...